# Angular how to return an async value in function

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I implemented a canDeactivate function which expects an observable of type boolean to be returned. Condition to leave is async so I can't do something like this for example:

```
public canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return of(true);
    }, 5000);
}
```

How can I make a request inside this function that will determine if I can leave or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use native rxjs for that, no need for timeouts

```
public canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return interval(5000).pipe(take(1),mapTo(true));
}
```

or

```
public canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return of(true).pipe(delay(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
public canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return new Observable<boolean>( observer => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      observer.next(true);
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Observable instance and return it

```
return new Observable(obs=>{
 setTimeout(() => {
        return obs.next(true);
    }, 5000);
)}
```

https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable